# Performance implications of autoboxing on ArrayList of primitive wrappers

Tags: java, collections, performance-testing, primitive, autoboxing

Java does not let us create `ArrayList` of primitives directly. But we can create a `ArrayList` of the primitives wrapper class.

But when accessing the primitive value , compiler automatically does the wrapping and unwrapping. Is this not an overhead ? My question is what are performance implications of this ?

In such a case wouldn't `int[]` perform better than `ArrayList<Integer>` ?

Has anyone measured performance of `int[]` vs `ArrayList<Inetger>` for `Java5.0` (when this was first introduced) and latter versions of Java. It would be really helpful for everybody who runs into this question , if you could share the test results.

Comment: An array and a `List` have different usages and it often doesn't come down to speed when choosing between them. Its also important to know that underneath every `ArrayList` is an array.

Comment: Primitive array is faster (no double about it) but `List` (and any collection in general) is more convenient for objects. So the choice is yours, but whatever you do do not use old array for public interface.

Comment: @Obicere true. I am trying to understand , if we are compromising on performance for a bit of flexibility. This is specific to  when we have to make choice between int[] and ArrayList<Inetger>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed it adds some overhead. If it is a problem for you, consider using some library supporting collections of primitives out of the box. For example [Trove](https://bitbucket.org/trove4j/trove), [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) or google for another library

Answer (score 2):

The primitive collections in libraries like [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), [FastUtil](https://fastutil.di.unimi.it/), [Trove](https://bitbucket.org/trove4j/trove/src/master/), [HPPC](https://github.com/carrotsearch/hppc), will save you memory and will often perform better than their boxed equivalents in Java. Each of the libraries will provide a richer set of methods than `int[]`. It is best for you to compare performance based on your specific use cases.

I found this Baeldung article titled a "[Performance Comparison of Primitive Lists in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-list-primitive-performance)" which compares FastUtil, Trove and Colt primitive lists.

The [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) open source library has several primitive collections including `List`, `Set`, `Bag`, `Stack` and `Map` supporting all primitive types. There have been a few articles written with performance benchmarks comparing performance of JDK Collections with Eclipse Collections primitive collections.

- [NatTable + Eclipse Collections = Performance & Memory Improvements?](http://blog.vogella.com/2020/06/25/nattable-eclipse-collections-performance-memory-improvements/)
- [Baeldung: Benchmark JDK Collections vs Eclipse Collections](https://www.baeldung.com/jdk-collections-vs-eclipse-collections)
- [Optimization Strategies with Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2018/april/collections.php)
- [Refactoring to Eclipse Collections](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Refactoring-to-Eclipse-Collections/)

The NatTable article has some comparisons between `int[]` and `List<Integer>`.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 0):

[A question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42333460/1098603) was asked on the same topic with the following benchmark results on a 20M elements `int[]` vs. `ArrayList` (which I re-run on my computer, from @Wsl_F question):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 20_000_000;
    System.out.println("Warming up...");
    list(n);
    array(n);
    long t0 = System.nanoTime();
    int v = list(n);
    t0 = System.nanoTime() - t0;
    System.out.printf("list %.1f ms (%d)\n", (t0 / 1000000.0), v);

    t0 = System.nanoTime();
    v = array(n);
    t0 = System.nanoTime() - t0;
    System.out.printf("array %.1f ms (%d)\n", (t0 / 1000000.0), v);
}

private static int list(int n) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        list.add(i);
    return list.get(n/2);
}

private static int array(int n) {
    int[] list = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        list[i] = i;
    return list[n/2];
}
```

Gives me (Eclipse on Ubuntu 16.04 x64 with Intel Core i7):

```
list 1839,9 ms (10000000)
array 515,9 ms (10000000)
```